# Including CSS Zend

Tags: css, zend-framework, styles, head

I'm trying to include a file named: "style.css" in my Zend layout named: "index.phtml".
My folder tree is:

```
    laltroposto
      |-public
      |   |-index.phtml
      |   |-css
      |   |   !-style.css
      |   !-...
      |-application
      |   |-layouts
      |   |   !-scripts
      |   |       !-index.phtml
      |   !...
      !-library
          !-...
```

This is my code for include css (it is into the head's tag):

```
<?php echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('css/style.css'); ?>
```

I tried also:

```
<?php echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/style.css'); ?>
```

This is my error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.laltroposto.com/js/jquery.js
```

Some help?

Comment: What is the output in the HTML? Are you getting that error when you view the page? As if so that has nothing to do with your css/style.css line.

Comment: No error, it work fine, but the css is not loaded, Chrome Inspect say to me: "GET http://www.laltroposto.com/css/style.css 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: Does your document root point at laltroposto/public? Can you post the contents of your htaccess?

Comment: I'm sorry, where I can find my htaccess?

Comment: You should have a .htaccess file in public (unless you have your rewrite rules somewhere else).

Comment: Please write your solution as an _answer_, not in the question. 1 year 4 months is sufficient time to learn how this site works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved hosting my site on www.laltroposto.org instead of www.laltroposto.com... I don't know why!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('css/style.css'); ?>
```

`/css/style.css = index.phtml/css/style.css`

You had a additional trailing slash before css!

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.laltroposto.com/js/jquery.js! well, as far as i know it means that your **jquery.js** was not found at the server! double check that if it exists or not!

Comment: It exist, I'm on localhost, running on an Apache server, and the file it's just here! :(

Comment: if on localhost change that link to : js/jquery.js and remove that laltroposto.com/ from it

Comment: This is just incorrect. There should be a slash at the start of the path - `/css/style.css` as you almost always want to use absolute paths rather than relative ones when including external resources.

Comment: @AspiringAqib jquery? I'm not sure of what you mean.

Comment: @TimFountain I tried also with the slash, but neither work!

Comment: @PizziraniLeonardo Well, You I included jQuery nah just change the source path (`src`) to `js/jquery.js`!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't got really a problem with your css file but with the js one : jquery.js

```
404 (Not Found) http://www.laltroposto.com/js/jquery.js
```

As it said before, do not forget to add the slash at the begining path of your js loaded files else it is considered like a route and it issue to a 404 error page.

hope that helps you.